# Geocoding v7 does not know streets that were available in Geocoding v6

Tags: here-api, geocoding, here-wego

I'm experiencing a problem with a specific address: Rue Robert Gérard, 1480 Saintes.
When I geocode this address and reverse geocode, I end up with Rue Gérard, Chastre as a result. This is about 60 km from the original address.

Moreover, the street does not seem to exist when I look it up via https://wego.here.com.
[image: Street where Rue Robert Gérard should be]

Up until the moment we switched to v7, this specific address never presented an issue.
Google Maps has no problems to find the address either.

Why is this street not included?
Can I find an overview of differences?